# Find the creator of an idle TCP connection

Tags: unix, solaris

On Solaris (or Unix), how can I find the remote host associated with the creation of a currently idle TCP connection?

`lsof` gives me a bunch of lines like this:

```
java    25375 foo 8161u  IPv4 0xfffffeb1f6f523c0        0t0        TCP *:* (IDLE)
```

But the `*:*` puzzles me - I was expecting to see something like

```
hostname:7000->10.199.132.158:54973 (IDLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pfiles 25375
```

Look for socket entries, you will see the originating local/remote source as an IP address.

```
nslookup [remote ip]
```

Will give you the server.domainname